# Unlocked Package with Dependency in a different folder

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package, sfdx-error

In the past I was able to have a base package with its repo in one folder and then in a completely separate folder the app package with its repo.  The `sfdx force:source:push` command would push the dependent code and the app code if it wasn't already there.  However, lately it seems something has changed since this is no longer the case for me.  I started getting `Unexpected file found in package directory: ..\Source Code\Salesforce\Base_Package\.git\FETCH_HEAD` errors when trying to create a package version with the Salesforce CLI.

The push command seems to ignore the dependent directory listed in the sfdx-project.json file and the version create command gives the above error.  The only workaround I found to get the push command to work, is if I move the Base_Package folder inside of the App_Package folder.  I haven't tried with the version create command yet.  Doing this is unsustainable since I have multiple App_Packages in different folders since each one has its own repo that are dependent on the Base_Package.

Config (Not working) - I know it is finding the folder because I do not get an invalid package directory error.
Folder Structure

- Base Package: ../Source Code/Salesforce/Base_Package
- App Package: ../Source Code/Salesforce/salesforce-core/app_package

sfdx-project.json file contents

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
      {
        "path": "../../Base_Package",
        "default": false,
        "package": "Base_Package",
        "versionName": "ver 1.0.XX",
        "versionNumber": "1.0.XX.NEXT"
    },
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true,
      "package": "App Package",
      "versionName": "ver 0.0.1",
      "versionNumber": "0.0.1.NEXT",
      "dependencies": [
        {
          "package": "Base_Package",
          "versionNumber": "1.0.XX.LATEST"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "pushPackageDirectoriesSequentially": true,
  "name": "app-package",
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "54.0",
  "packageAliases": {
    "Base_Package": "0H...",
    "Base_Package@1.0.XX-1": "04t...",
    "Base_Package@1.0.XX-2": "04t...",
    "Base_Package@1.0.XX-3": "04t..."
  }
}
```

Config (Works but not feasable to move the Base_Package to each App_Package folder for development or package version creation.)
Folder Structure

- Base Package: ../Source Code/Salesforce/Salesforce-core/app_package/Base_Package
- App Package: ../Source Code/Salesforce/salesforce-core/app_package

sfdx-project.json file contents

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
      {
        "path": "./Base_Package",
        "default": false,
        "package": "Base_Package",
        "versionName": "ver 1.0.XX",
        "versionNumber": "1.0.XX.NEXT"
    },
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true,
      "package": "App Package",
      "versionName": "ver 0.0.1",
      "versionNumber": "0.0.1.NEXT",
      "dependencies": [
        {
          "package": "Base_Package",
          "versionNumber": "1.0.XX.LATEST"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "pushPackageDirectoriesSequentially": true,
  "name": "app-package",
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "54.0",
  "packageAliases": {
    "Base_Package": "0H...",
    "Base_Package@1.0.XX-1": "04t...",
    "Base_Package@1.0.XX-2": "04t...",
    "Base_Package@1.0.XX-3": "04t..."
  }
}
```

Also tested the above with the easy-spaces-lwc repo since they have multiple folders with code and the same issue occurs when I move one of the folders outside of the main folder and redirect the sfdx-project.json folder path to the new location.

Any ideas on how to make it work like it did at first, so the Base_Package could be located in a common folder that the extension packages could reference?

Dev Environment:
Windows 10
VS Code v1.66.2
sfdx-cli/7.146.1 win32-x64 node-v16.14.2
Salesforce Extension Pack v54.8.0
sfdx plugins --core result:
@oclif/help 1.0.1
@oclif/plugin-autocomplete 0.3.0 (core)
@oclif/plugin-commands 1.3.0 (core)
@oclif/plugin-help 3.3.1 (core)
@oclif/plugin-not-found 1.2.6 (core)
@oclif/plugin-plugins 1.10.11 (core)
@oclif/plugin-update 1.5.0 (core)
@oclif/plugin-warn-if-update-available 1.7.3 (core)
@oclif/plugin-which 1.0.4 (core)
@salesforce/lwc-dev-mobile 1.5.1
@salesforce/lwc-dev-server 2.11.0
@salesforce/sfdx-plugin-lwc-test 0.1.7 (core)
alias 2.0.0 (core)
apex 0.11.0 (core)
auth 1.8.2 (core)
community 1.1.4 (core)
config 1.3.30 (core)
custom-metadata 1.0.12 (core)
data 0.6.12 (core)
generator 1.2.2 (core)
info 2.0.0 (core)
limits 2.0.0 (core)
org 1.11.2 (core)
salesforce-alm 54.1.0 (core)
schema 2.0.0 (core)
sfdx-cli 7.146.1 (core)
source 1.9.3 (core)
telemetry 1.4.0 (core)
templates 54.3.0 (core)
trust 1.1.0 (core)
user 1.7.1 (core)

**Update - Visual Folder Structure**

```
Source Code/
  |__ Salesforce/
      |__ Base_Package/
      |   |__ .git/
      |   |__ .sfdx/
      |   |__ data/
      |   |__ force-app
      |   |__ .forceignore
      |   |__ .gitignore
      |   |__ README.md
      |__ salesforce-core/
          |__ App_Package
              |__ .git/
              |__ .sfdx/
              |__ .vscode/
              |__ config/
              |__ force-app/
              |__ scripts/
              |__ .forceignore
              |__ .gitignore
              |__ package.json
              |__ package-lock.json
              |__ README.md
              |__ sfdx-project.json
```

Comment: The error makes it look like your .git is in the wrong place, at a lower point in the folder structure (within a packageDirectory). It should be in the project root directory. If you have to have it in this unorthodox location, try adding a .forceignore entry to exclude this .git folder.

Comment: @PhilW - Thanks for the response, the git folders are in the root folder for each of their respective repos.  i.e. ../Source Code/Salesforce/salesforce-core/app_package/.git and /Source Code/Salesforce/Base_Package/.git.  I tried to add to the .forceignore file as well and it doesn't seems to have an affect

Comment: What did you try to add in .forceignore? It needs to be like `**/.git/**`.

Comment: I had `../../Base_Package/.git/**` since I have a data folder for importing common data in there as well and `../../Base_Package/data/**` worked in ignoring that folder.  Changed to your suggestion and still getting the same error when building the package, unexpected file.

Comment: Not sure why the .forceignore entry doesn't side-step this issue, but I still think the .git folder seems to be in the wrong place since it is within a packageDirectory.

Comment: Where in git do you store the sfdx-project.json etc. that appear in the root folder, above the package directories?

Comment: Thanks for helping @PhilW, I appreciate your time.  The folder structure for the app_package is:  
.git (folder), .sfdx (folder), config (folder), force-app (folder), manifest (folder),  scripts (folder), .forceignore (file), .gitignore (file), README.md (file), sfdx-project.json (file).  The Base_Package structure is similar except there is no sfdx-project.json file.

Comment: Can you perhaps [edit] the question to provide the file and folder structure as a bit of an ASCII art diagram (showing the .git folder(s) as well as the various important files you listed in your comment? I need to get my head around how the app_package and Base_Package interrelate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your structure the sfdx-project.json must include some "../" in the path to the base package (you show "./").

This structuring is fragile, due to the in-file-system-only folder-based structural relationship across git repositories - it relies on the developer to carefully create the base folder structure and place git repo clones in the right place.

I am surprised it previously worked, to be honest (though, as per the comments, I am not clear why using a `.forceignore` entry of `**/.git/**` doesn't work).

Salesforce recommends what they call a "monorepo" for this (read more [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/209831/git-repo-design-pattern-for-sfdx-projects)); a single SFDX **project**, in one git repository, that includes folders for multiple packages (here your base package and your app package).

You would restructure your code into a single git repository, thus:

```
project
  |__ .git/
  |__ .sfdx/
  |__ .vscode/
  |__ config/
  |__ force-base/
  |     |__ ...
  |__ force-app/
  |     |__ ...
  |__ scripts/
  |__ .forceignore
  |__ .gitignore
  |__ package.json
  |__ package-lock.json
  |__ README.md
  |__ sfdx-project.json
```

The sfdx-project.json would be similar to yours:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
      {
        "path": "force-base",
        "default": false,
        "package": "Base_Package",
        "versionName": "ver 1.0.XX",
        "versionNumber": "1.0.XX.NEXT"
    },
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true,
      "package": "App Package",
      "versionName": "ver 0.0.1",
      "versionNumber": "0.0.1.NEXT",
      "dependencies": [
        {
          "package": "Base_Package",
          "versionNumber": "1.0.XX.LATEST"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "pushPackageDirectoriesSequentially": true,
  "name": "app-package",
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "54.0",
  "packageAliases": {
    "Base_Package": "0H...",
    "Base_Package@1.0.XX-1": "04t...",
    "Base_Package@1.0.XX-2": "04t...",
    "Base_Package@1.0.XX-3": "04t..."
  }
}
```

If you definitely don't want to restructure to follow Salesforce's structuring you have two options:

1. See if you can work out an appropriate `.forceignore` entry (maybe `../**/.git/**`?).
2. Break the double-package-directory push and instead actually install the dependency (Base Package) as part of your scratch org creation, using scripting, instead of pushing its content. Of course, this can cause namespace issues and may not be achievable in all cases.